Error when making CoqProject
I have a folder with 3 coq-files, say file_1.v, file_2.v and file_3.v, and I want to create a _CoqProject so that I can import one file in the other. I've followed the usual guidelines, but they did not work for me; I encountered an error. Here is what I did:
I created a _CoqProject file in the same folder the .v-files are in. I wrote into it:
-R . Project_name

file_1.v
file_2.v
file_3.v

Then I opened cygwin, went to the directory these files are in and ran the following commands:
$ coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o CoqMakefile
$ make -f CoqMakefile

The first command executes without problems and creates files CoqMakefile, CoqMakefile.conf and .CoqMakefile.d .
However running the second command in cygwin returns the following error:
$ make -f CoqMakefile VERBOSE=1
"coqdep"  -vos -dyndep var -f _CoqProject   > ".CoqMakefile.d" || ( RV=$?; rm -f ".CoqMakefile.d"; exit $RV )
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe --no-print-directory -f "CoqMakefile" pre-all
make[1]: CoqMakefile pre-all: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'CoqMakefile pre-all'.  Stop.
make: *** [CoqMakefile:408: all] Error 2

Running it in Windows PowerShell instead returns:
> make -f CoqMakefile VERBOSE=1
'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
-e was unexpected at this time.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, true "COQDEP VFILES", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe --no-print-directory -f "CoqMakefile" pre-all
'cut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
-e was unexpected at this time.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, true "COQDEP VFILES", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, # Extension point, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [CoqMakefile:475: pre-all] Error 2
make: *** [CoqMakefile:408: all] Error 2

The error seems to stem from line 408 of the CoqMakefile. Lines 407-411 of that file look like this:
all:
    $(HIDE)$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -f "$(SELF)" pre-all
    $(HIDE)$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -f "$(SELF)" real-all
    $(HIDE)$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -f "$(SELF)" post-all
.PHONY: all

The rule pre-all, that it does not find, is defined lower in the code as such:
# Extension points for actions to be performed before/after the all target
pre-all::
    @# Extension point
    $(HIDE)if [ "$(COQMAKEFILE_VERSION)" != "$(COQ_VERSION)" ]; then\
      echo "W: This Makefile was generated by Coq $(COQMAKEFILE_VERSION)";\
      echo "W: while the current Coq version is $(COQ_VERSION)";\
    fi
.PHONY: pre-all

Does anyone know how to handle this?
I already triple-checked my spelling in the _CoqProject file.
I'm running Coq 8.18 on Windows 11. I have GNU Make 4.4.1 and have tried both the Windows PowerShell and cygwin64.

Please don't use screen captures, but plain text instead.

The error message suggests that the -f option is not recognized correctly. Can you give details about your shell (WSL? powershell?) ? And also which version of make you use?

I've added the details to the end of the question. And also added a more explicit error-message. :)

I don’t know chocolatey well but make whould be fine. Maybe the use of a different makefile name triggers some bug. Can you try with the standard name « Makefile ». Note that any local make rules is supposed to be put in Makefile.local.

Changing the name to Makefile did not make a difference. I looked into the code of the Makefile and copied the parts where the Error seems to come from. The pre-all rule is defined there, but there is no Makefile.local, doese there need to be one?

can you check that make is gnumake ? I suspect that there is something with the :: rule that triggers an error with your specific version of make.

Yes $ make --version returns GNU Make 4.4.1

I also added the error that Windows PowerShell returns, which contains a bit more information, but ultimately says the same.

This may work:
eval `opam env`
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile
make


I tried it and I still get the same error.

@StiftungWarentest I'm sorry... I'm working on WSL2, Window10, but both of them work in my computer.
